# How to enable cache-control for static assets in dropwizard

Tags: java, caching, filter, browser-cache, dropwizard

I am trying to enable caching but still not working.No response headers are setted.

Configured static assets.
In yml:

```
assets: 
  overrides:
     /sale/images/: /tmp/deals/images/
```

Here is the code I have used for enable caching,

```
  import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.Date;

        import javax.servlet.Filter;
        import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
        import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

        public class CacheControlFilter implements Filter {

            public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,

                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

                HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

                // Add whatever headers you want here

                resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "pubic, max-age=100000");

                resp.setHeader("Expires", new Date().getTime() + 500000 + "");
                resp.setContentType("image/*");
                chain.doFilter(request, response);

            }

            public void destroy() {
            }

            public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
            }

        }
```

And in the Application class,included this in run method,

```
 environment.servlets().addFilter("/sale/images/", new CacheControlFilter()).
            addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");
```

If anyone knows,please help me to solve this.

Comment: Probably the configurable assets bundle is interfering with your setup. For me your code works, and was very helpful!